# PHP, variable and function in separate files

Tags: php, function, variables

I have 2 files:

file1 - variables.php

```
$variable = something;
```

and file2 - functions.php

```
function somefunction() {    
    do_something_with $variable;
}
```

How can I use variable, defined in one file, in function defined in second file?

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: see no question here...

Comment: This is basic RTFM stuff! http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Comment: You haven't actually tried anything, have you?

Answer (score 0):

use include_once / require_once "file2" inside file1 and call the "somefunction" with $variable as argument.